# Should a new basement window have flashing around it?

Tags: egress

I hired a local contractor to install an egress window for me and he did some odd stuff.  I plan to have him fix it but I want to make sure to ask for the right stuff.  I don't know much about installing windows but shouldn't there be some type of flashing, molding, and or foam used here?  Any input will help.

[image: window]

Comment: I agree with Jack--if it wasn't spelled out in your contract at all you're out of luck. You need to contact your inspection office and ask why flashing wasn't considered necessary. Fortunately this is a fairly easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on what exactly the contract called for. Hopefully you got a contract that spelled out everything that the contractor was responsible for, like trim, molding, foam, etc.

Comment: The contract say install egress window according to local code.  It passed inspection, but it looks like there are gaps between the wood and brick where water can get in.  That can't be normal.